# Batchfile: How to copy files containing spaces to folder using a loop

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, filenames, space

I wrote a batchfile that goes trough a directory, finds all files with ending *.doc and copies those to the folder Results. Also the names of the files are written to a tmp.txt-file.

This runs well for files that do not contain spaces but fails for filenames with spaces. **How would I change my code in order to find filenames with spaces as well?**

I know that I need to somehow wrap them with "" which I did in the last line (works OK if I manually create files with spaces in Result-folder)

```
set dSource=c:\Users\S\Desktop\Batchtest\*.doc
set dTarget="c:\Users\S\Desktop\Batchtest\Result"
set fType=*.doc

pause
@echo off    

  rem start at the top of the tree to visit and loop though each directory
  for /r %%a in (*.doc) do (
  rem enter the directory
  pushd %%a
  echo In directory:
  cd
  copy %%a  c:\Users\S\Desktop\Batchtest\Result"
  rem leave the directory
  popd
  )


echo all content of result: 
dir "c:\Users\S\Desktop\Batchtest\Result\*.doc" /s /b /a-d > tmp.txt
```

Comment: Enclose _each_ full (file)name in quotes: `copy "%%a"  "c:\Users\S\Desktop\Batchtest\Result"`. Be aware that `for /R` command process files, _not_ directories. I suggest you to check your `pushd %%a` command (unless you are sure that _all_ directories does not have spaces, and that _all_ files do have spaces)

Comment: PS - Your `dir` last line does _not_ need quotes because `c:\Users\S\Desktop\Batchtest\Result\*.doc` name does not contain spaces by itself, although it is a good practice to enclose _all_ names in quotes.

Comment: `pushd %%a` should be `pushd "%%~dpa"` for the reasons explained by Aacini. See `for /?` for an explanation of the `%%~` modifiers.